# Inter process communication on the same machine,signal or socket,how to decide?

Tags: c, sockets, ipc, signals

It seems to me that both `signal` and `socket` can be used for this job,

how do you decide which one to use actually?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the information which would be communicated between the two process? There are many Interprocess communication methods.

Comment: Using signals for IPC is like choosing pidgeons for mail. There are more convenient alternatives.

Comment: Avoid signals if you possibly can; they are very primitive and limited in what they can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using signals for IPC is sort of inconvenient and primitive. You should really be choosing between Unix sockets (not TCP ones!) and pipes.

Pipes are generally easier to program with, since they guarantee that a single `write` under the size of `PIPE_BUF` is atomic. They do have their limitations however. For example, when the writer is faster than the reader, the writer starts to block when the pipe buffer gets full. The size of this buffer by default is around 64k, and it cannot be changed without recompiling the kernel, at least in Linux. Pipes are also unidirectional, which means that you'll have to keep a pair of pipes in each process, one for reading and one for writing.

Unix sockets have a configurable send buffer size and a more advanced programming interface.

Comment: Pipes do not make any guarantees about reads/writes like that, and it's easy to construct a simple program to show that one `read` can combine multiple `write` calls. (See: http://pastebin.com/LxbreJke) Also, one generally should not make assumptions about the buffer size (the 64k buffer is a fairly recent change: I've often had older Linux boxen, as people resist updating.). The *primary difference* between pipes and sockets is that a FIFO pipe is one-way, a Unix socket is two-way.